# Use env var for package version in Pipefile

Tags: pipenv, pipenv-install

env file `MY_PACKAGE=1.1` but I get "Invalid value" error when running `pipenv install`. I am using pipenv, version 2023.9.8. I wonder if Pipenv supports this. Thanks

```
[packages]
  my-package1 = {version=${MY_PACKAGE}, index="testpypi"}
```